# SQL query for Selecting child

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion, common-table-expression

Iam using the following stored procedure for select all child units of the given unit id.For `each unit only one child` is there and no child for least unit

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UnitSelectChildByID] 
@company_ID INT,
@unit_ID INT

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @parent INT
    SET @parent=@unit_ID
    DECLARE @temp TABLE(id int)
    WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM tblUnit WHERE parent_ID=@parent) >0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temp SELECT unit_ID FROM tblUnit WHERE parent_ID=@parent
    SET @parent=(SELECT unit_ID FROM tblUnit WHERE parent_ID=@parent) 
    END
    SELECT 
         unit_ID
         ,short_Name AS unit     
    FROM 
         tblUnit 
    WHERE 
        unit_ID IN (SELECT id FROM @temp) OR unit_ID=@unit_ID
END
```

This is working properly.What i want to know is any better method is there for select child units by `avoiding while loop and table variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using recursion, which CTEs are good for.

```
WITH Units (unit_ID, short_Name)
AS
(
    --initial select of the main parent
    Select unit_ID, short_Name
    From tblUnit
    Where unit_ID = @unit_ID

    Union All

    --plus the recursive self join of the sub units
    Select unit_ID, short_Name
    From tblUnit
    Inner Join Units On Units.unit_ID = tblUnit.parent_ID
)

Select unit_ID, short_Name
From Units
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Common Table Expressions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Note that I haven't actually tried the below SQL, I just modified the example on the MSDN page to use your table and column definitions.

```
WITH UnitChildren (unit_ID, short_Name)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT u.unit_ID, short_Name, 0 AS Level
    FROM tblUnit AS u
    WHERE unit_ID = @unit_ID
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT u.unit_ID, short_Name, Level + 1
    FROM tblUnit AS u
    INNER JOIN UnitChildren AS uc
        ON u.unit_ID = uc.parent_ID
)

-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT * FROM UnitChildren 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only two levels in hierarchy by design:

```
SELECT    u.unit_ID, u.short_Name
FROM      tblUnit AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN
              tblUnit AS p ON u.parent_ID = p.unit_ID
WHERE     ISNULL(u.parent_ID, u.unit_ID) = @unit_ID
```

Comment: Replaced `ISNULL(p.parent_ID, @unit_ID)` with `ISNULL(u.parent_ID, u.unit_ID)`. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: yes, if you have more than two levels (aka children for other children) this will not work for your scenario, as I mentioned above.